# How I can reach dropdown links' contents from another page with jquery and html?

Tags: html, jquery, css

I have a page to build with html css and jquery from my customer. I have a menu with dropdown list and dropdown links' html codes are all in the same page but the content is changing when you click the related link. The page remains the same , just the content data is changing when you click the links. And for example when I am in home page, I want to go to these contents. Since I don't use react, I have to use navbar in every page separately.

[image]

My content changing page (plasticsurgery.html file) code structure is below. Here in the navbar part:

For the nav link I use below code to get the contents from the links

```html
<a href="#" class="text-div" data-content="content1">Lorem Ipsum</a>
```

below is a short part of my first content div code

```html
<div class="sections" id="content1">
  <section>
    <div class="row plasticsurgery-title title1">
      <h3>Lorem ipsum</h3>
    </div>
  </section>

  <section>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-12 first-explanation">
        <h4>
          Lorem ipsum
        </h4>
        <p>
         Lorem ipsum
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</div>
```

And jquery changes the contents here according to attributes "data-content="content1" and "id=content1"
Since this navbar and the content divs are on the same hmtl page, I can reach the content datas and change them.
But when I am in the home page and click the second dropdown link, I cannot get the content data.
below code is not working in the home page to reach the contents because # will not go to anywhere if you are on a different page. And if I put the html file path in the href, it directs you to the page itself (plasticsurgery.html) but always takes the first content as default. When you click the second dropdown link, it still takes the first one. How can arrange my a tag to direct to the contents from home page ?
Here I am not trying to reach a page. I want to reach different contents ( changing contents ) of a page.

```html
<a href="#" class="text-div" data-content="content1">Lorem Ipsum</a>
```

Comment: please edit your question and add your jQuery-code and the HTML-code of your `nav` - at least the `a` tags.

Comment: my jquery code for content change is
$(".dropdown-container").find("a.text-div").click(function () {
  var content = $(this).data("content");
  $("#" + content).show();
  $("#" + content).siblings(".sections").hide();
})

Comment: nav code 
<div class="dropdown-links">
                      <a href="#" class="title">
                        Göğüs Operasyonları
                      </a>
                      <a href="/plasticsurgery.html#">Meme Büyütme</a>
                      <a href="#">Meme Küçültme</a>
                      <a href="#">Meme Dikleştirme</a>
                      <a href="#">Erkekte Meme Estetiği</a>
                    </div>

Comment: under your question is a Link (small grey text) that is called "Edit". Click it and paste the code there - not in the comments!

Comment: The links in your nav code have no data attribute like `data-content="content1"` and no class like `.text-div`...

Comment: the attributes are in plasticsurgery.hmtl page navbar not in the home page. when is use these attributes in the home page, it doesnt work

Comment: Then post all the code that is necessary to reproduce the issue in the stack snippet in your question! I'm out until you have done this...